# Поиск ближайшего времени из списка

Tags: java, android, строки, дата, время

Добрый день. У меня есть строка, в ней расположено время ("10:00; 10:20, 09:40, и т.д."). Мне необходимо выводить пользователю ближайшее время.
Хотел получать текущее время и сравнивать через строку, однако возникла проблема с добавлением к времени минуты, если совпадений не найдено.
Как и через что можно это реализовать?

Comment: После приведения времени к секундам задача сведется к поиску ближайшего числа из некоторого набора чисел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строку преобразовываем в массив. Записываем в переменную today текущую дату в формате mm/dd/yyyy. Получаем в tnow текущее время в миллисекундах с начала эпохи Unix. Проходим по массиву в цикле, к каждому значению времени спереди приставляем today, чтобы получить строку в формате дата-время. Преобразуем эту строку в миллисекунды с начала эпохи Unix. Вычитаем текущее время и находим минимальную разницу. Результат выводим в консоли.

```js
s = "10:00, 10:20, 09:40";
sa = s.split(',');

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

var now = new Date();
var tnow = now.getTime();

var tmin = -1;
var tdiff = 0;

jQuery.each(sa, function(key, value) {
  t = Date.parse(today + ' ' + value);
  tdiff = Math.abs(t - tnow);
  if (tmin < 0) tmin = tdiff;
  if (tdiff < tmin) tmin = tdiff;
})
console.log(tmin / 1000/ 3600);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```